# Set theory magic on list of tuples

Tags: python, list, set, tuples, set-theory

In python I have two lists `A` and `B`. Both lists consist of tuples `(x,y)`. For example:

```
A = [('x1','y1'), ('x2','y2'), ('x3','y3')]
B = [('x1','y1'), ('x2','y5'), ('x4','y4')]
```

Now, there are three results I want. All of them are easily solvable with set theory, if only there were no tuples involved.

Result 1: Intersection of both lists:`set(A) & set(B)`). So result should be comparing both values of the tuples of both lists. Result should be: `C = [('x1','y1')]`

Result 2: Intersection of both lists where only the `(x,y)[0]` matches. Result should be: `D = (('x1','y1'), ('x2', ('y2', 'y5'))]`. Ideally the solution is `D - C -> E = [('x2', ('y2', 'y5'))]` but I can live with having `D` itself.

Result 3: The uniques of list `B` compared to `A`: `set(B)-(set(A) & set(B))`. Only compared on `(x,y)[0]`. Result should be: `[('x4', 'y4')]`.

I couldn't find anything on these problems, and wasn't able to construct a solution myself. Can anyone help?

Comment: Just a note, wouldn't Result 3 be `[(x2,y5), (x4,y4)]`?

Comment: Did you try anything? `tuple` is hashable, so you can convert `A` / `B` to sets and do what you want.

Comment: @Mathias you are absolutely right. I updated the question :).

Comment: You're missing a `)` at the end of `A`

Comment: @PM2Ring fixed. Also added quotes to immediate copy-pasting to python shell is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some ways to do what you want using dicts. This is Python 2 code; it will need some minor modification for Python 3. IIRC, Python 3 doesn't have `dict.iteritems()` since its `dict.items()` returns an iterator instead of a list.

```
A = [('x1','y1'), ('x2','y2'), ('x3','y3')]
B = [('x1','y1'), ('x2','y5'), ('x4','y4')]

dA = dict(A)
dB = dict(B)

#Intersection, the simple way
print 'Result 1a:', list(set(A) & set(B))

#Intersection using dicts instead of sets
result = [(k, vA) for k, vA in dA.iteritems() if dB.get(k) == vA]
print 'Result 1b:', result

#match on 1st tuple element, ignoring 2nd element
result = {}
for k, vA in dA.iteritems():
    vB = dB.get(k)
    if vB:
        result[k] = (vA, vB) if vB != vA else vA
print 'Result 2a:', result.items()

#match on 1st tuple element only if 2nd elements don't match
result = {}
for k, vA in dA.iteritems():
    vB = dB.get(k)
    if vB and vB != vA:
        result[k] = (vA, vB)
print 'Result 2b:', result.items()

#unique elements of B, ignoring 2nd element
result = [(k, vB) for k, vB in dB.iteritems() if k not in dA]
print 'Result  3:', result
```

**output**

```
Result 1a: [('x1', 'y1')]
Result 1b: [('x1', 'y1')]
Result 2a: [('x2', ('y2', 'y5')), ('x1', 'y1')]
Result 2b: [('x2', ('y2', 'y5'))]
Result  3: [('x4', 'y4')]
```

Comment: Great answer, provided all possible solutions. Thank you very much :).

Comment: Note that converting `A` and `B` to dicts will discard points that share the same x-coordinate. Try e.g. `A = [('x1', 'y1'), ('x1', 'y2')]`.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini: That's a _very_ good point. Hopefully, it's a non-issue for Tim's use-case.

Comment: @Tim: Will your lists contain points as per Andrea's example? If so, my code will need some modification. Or you can just use Andrea's code. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring I understand the confusion. In my case it will be a bunch of strings. I displayed it as `'xn'` and `'yn'` as being just variables. They are not coordinates. Your code works fine just the way it is. I needed to convert the dicts to lists though but that's an implementation detail and not part or important for the question.

Comment: @Tim: Phew! :) Are you converting the dicts to lists after the membership testing? Or are you using lists instead of dicts to do the testing? The reason I ask is that `if v in obj:` is _much_ more efficient when `obj` is a set or dict than when `obj` is a list or tuple, unless it's only got a very small number of members.

Comment: I'm doing it all the way in the end. After all the logic :).

Answer (score 1):

why not use python's `set()` ? 1 is very direct, 2 is requires just a little more work:

```
A = [('x1','y1'), ('x2','y2'), ('x3','y3')]
B = [('x1','y1'), ('x2','y5'), ('x4','y4')]

a,b = set(A),set(B)
print '1:',a&b

axs = set(map(itemgetter(0),A))
bxs = set(map(itemgetter(0),B))

result2 = []
for c in axs&bxs:
    result2.append((c,set([y for x,y in A+B if x==c]))
print '2:',result2
```

output:

```
1: set([('x1', 'y1')])
2: [('x2', set(['y2', 'y5'])), ('x1', set(['y1']))]
```

you can use a very similar approach for 3

Comment: That won't work for case 3 because Tim only wants to test on the first element of each tuple, as in case 2.

Comment: @Tim didn't notice that 3 should only depend on x matches as well, updated

Comment: Although this answer is more pythonic, I accepted the other answer for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Intersection of both lists:**

   You already know the solution: `set(A) & set(B)`. Or, equivalently, `set(A).intersection(B)`.

   ```
   >>> A = [('x1', 'y1'), ('x2', 'y2'), ('x3', 'y3')]
   >>> B = [('x1', 'y1'), ('x2', 'y5'), ('x4', 'y4')]
   >>> set(A).intersection(B)
   {('x1', 'y1')}
   ```
2. **Intersection of both lists where only the (x,y)[0] matches:**

   First, make sure that both `A` and `B` are sorted by their x coordinate.

   Then use [itertools.groupby()](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and dictionaries:

   ```
   >>> a_grouped = {x: list(points) for x, points in
   ...              itertools.groupby(A, lambda point: point[0])}
   >>> b_grouped = {x: list(points) for x, points in
   ...              itertools.groupby(B, lambda point: point[0])}
   >>> [(x, {point[1] for point in a_grouped[x] + b_grouped[x]})
   ...  for x in a_grouped if x in b_grouped]
   [('x2', {'y5', 'y2'}), ('x1', {'y1'})]
   ```

   (This isn't quite the same as you asked, because, as you can see, we have  `('x1', {'y1'})` instead of `('x1', 'y1')`. Also, we have sets instead of lists, but these are both things that are trivial to fix.)

   If you want to exclude the common points: remove them from `A` and `B` just before calling groupby():

   ```
   >>> A = set(A)
   >>> B = set(B)
   >>> common_points = A & B
   >>> A = [point for point in A if point not in common_points]
   >>> B = [point for point in B if point not in common_points]
   ```
3. **The uniques of list `B` compared to `A`, only compared on `(x,y)[0]`:**

   Construct the set of all x coordinates of the points in `A`:

   ```
   >>> exclude = {point[0] for point in A}
   >>> [point for point in B if point[0] not in exclude]
   [('x4', 'y4')]
   ```

   Note that the elements of `exclude` are the keys of `a_grouped` -- this means that you can reuse part of the code from the previous problem and write:

   ```
   >>> [point for point in B if point[0] not in a_grouped]
   [('x4', 'y4')]
   ```

For all these solutions, both performance and readability can be improved, consider this if you're going to use my code.